# Manipulando divisíveis de 3 e 5

Tags: java, for

Estou com um enunciado que diz que tenho que fazer um looping entre 4 e 24, somando o index com um valor total, com alguns poréns:

1. Se o número do index for múltiplo de 5, ele deve somar 3;
2. Se o número do index for múltiplo de 3, ele deve subtrair 4;
3. Se for múltiplo de 3 e 5, deve multiplicar o valor total por 2;

O resultado final deve dar 190.

Meu código:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
         int total = 0;

        for (int i = 4; i <= 24; i++) {

            //Somo o index com o valor total
            if ((i % 5 > 0) && (i % 3 > 0)) {
                total += i;
            }

            //Caso true a opção 3
            if ((i % 5 == 0) && (i % 3 == 0)) {
                total *= 2;
            }

            //Caso true a opção 2
            if (i % 3 == 0) {
                total -= 4;
            }

            //Caso true a opção 1
            if (i % 5 == 0) {
                total += 3;
            }

        }   
        System.out.println(total);
    }

}
```

Meu resultado não sai do 189, nunca a 190, eu debuguei mas aparentemente minha lógica está certa. O que posso mudar para que chegue a 190 corretamente?

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi, as opções 1, 2, e 3 são excludentes: somente uma delas deve ser executada.

Mas no seu código, quando o número é múltiplo de 5 e 3 ao mesmo tempo, ele cai em dois `if`'s: no que testa se é múltiplo de 3 e 5 e depois no que testa se é múltiplo de 5.

Mas pelo que entendi do enunciado, se ele for múltiplo de 5 e 3, ele não deve entrar na condição "somente múltiplo de 5". Então basta colocar um `else` em cada `if`.

Outro detalhe é que para verificar se um número é múltiplo de 5 e 3 ao mesmo tempo, basta verificar se ele é múltiplo de 15:

```
int total = 0;
for (int i = 4; i <= 24; i++) {
    if (i % 5 > 0 && i % 3 > 0) {
        total += i;
    } else if (i % 15 == 0) {
        total *= 2;
    } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
        total += 3;
    } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
        total -= 4;
    }
}
System.out.println(total);
```

Com isso o resultado é 190.